# can't get popovers component to work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

According to this, http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/popover, shows the documentation on how this is supposed to work...quoted below may be the bit I'm not understanding (it's a little confusing because this all mentions tooltips and not popovers but I'm making a leap that since it's all in the same documentation that it's all related...)

(controllers)dashboard.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Bootstrap.TooltipBoxController=Ember.Controller.extend({

       hoverPop: Ember.Object.create({
          title: "I'm a title!",
          content: "And i'm a content!",
          trigger: "hover",
          placement: "right",
          sticky: true
      })
});
```

(templates)dashboard.hbs

```
<div class="pageheader">
     {{bs-bind-popover hoverPop}} ? 
</div>
```

application.js inside this file i have:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  renderTemplate: function() {
    // Render default outlet
    this.render();
    // render extra outlets
    var controller = this.controllerFor('tooltip-box');
    this.render("bs-tooltip-box", {
        outlet: "bs-tooltip-box",
        controller: controller,
        into: "application" // important when using at root level
    });
  },  
....
```

Ember console:
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (refers to this line `export default Bootstrap.TooltipBoxController=Ember.Controller.extend({`

Any ideas? Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: Not sure about this specific problem but fyi that lib is gaining dust.

Comment: I don't care of this. I just want  to run the above example.

Comment: Can you put add a breakpoint at that line and see what's not defined?

Comment: I got this error now. Handlebars error: Could not find property 'bs-bind-popover' on object

Comment: Bootstrap.TooltipBoxController is undefined.